# How can I Add pin Mark to Image in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I Add pin Mark to Image and get the Current Position of this Mark in xamarin.forms

Comment: as written this question doesn't make any sense.  Please [edit] it to include more useful detail about what you are trying to accomplish.  Adding a mockup of the UI you are trying to build may be helpful.  Please read [ask] for more guidance on writing an on-topic question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom renders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin) to custom the pin in each platform like:

**Ios:**

```
protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
{
    MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

    if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
        return null;

    var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
    if (customPin == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
    }

    annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Name);
    if (annotationView == null)
    {
        annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Name);
        annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
        annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
        annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
        annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
        ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Name = customPin.Name;
        ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;
    }
    annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

    return annotationView;
}
```

**android:**

```
protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
{
    var marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
    marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
    marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
    return marker;
}
```